# Python Scipt Killed by OOM during FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator. Is this normal/expected behaviour?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to generate a Time-Varying LQR using `FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator` for a system with a free-floating base + 7DoF arm: 14 positions + 13 velocities in state space. The trajectory which I'm trying to stabilize with TVLQR has 50-knot points. The Q and R matrices are simple diagonal matrices.

I create a time-varying linear system from the trajectory with custom linearization to handle the quaternions. So the time-varying linear system has 13 positions + 13 velocities in the state space. This is then used for the `FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator`. Previously, I was able to do so easily with floating base and 3 DoF arm but the same process uses too much memory for a 7 DoF arm.

However, when I try to run `FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator` to create the K matrices for the TVLQR, the Python process is killed by my OS (Ubuntu 22.04) by the OOM killer. I have 16GB of RAM and 8GB of swap both of which are completely filled during running the script after which the process is killed.

Is this expected/normal behavior?

Comment: My first guess is that you have a system that is numerically stiff -- it is trying to take exceedingly small timesteps (and record the Riccati solution at each of those timesteps).  There are various ways that you could check this; the easiest would be to add some logging to the c++ method (but you could also do it with a python LeafSystem that prints the time inside the CalcTimeDerivatives method).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am not sure I understand correctly how to add logging to the function as there is no Diagram/Simulator in the script. The only System is the TrajectoryAffineSystem from linearized matrices passed to the FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator function.

Comment: If you want to share some code with me, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Sure! I've created a minimal example I could create for creating a TVLQR for a given trajectory for the floating base + 7DoF arm system. The deepnote link contains the script to reproduce the error along with the required urdf and trajectory file.

https://deepnote.com/workspace/vyas-shubham-627c94cc-2a4c-4400-91a0-d9be3eb6cc37/project/TVLQR-OOM-Example-4b5668ec-8d03-4f92-9bc6-1133b4beb141/notebook/TVLQR%20OOM%20Example-45b0a744adef4b538d446e560403187c

I can also give an example if needed where the same method works for a 3DoF arm system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproduction (in the comments above).  I added a printout to the `DoCalcTimeDerivatives` method of the `RiccatiSystem` in `finite_horizon_linear_quadratic_regulator.cc`, and confirmed that your system is making the numerical integration stiff (the integrator is taking arbitrarily small time-steps around time -4.765 seconds). The right solution is to understand and resolve that stiffness in your system/trajectory pair.

A reasonable feature request would be to have more support for integrator options in FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulator.  Internally, it is using the ["dense integration"](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_integrator_base.html#a0cdd4796b7f98a09da058b9764f13b86) feature of the Drake integrators; but those integrators have many other settable options to e.g. control the minimum step size (at the expense of limited numerical accuracy). Those might conceivably help you debug the issue here.

Probably the actual API would be to support passing a reference to an existing integrator into the `FiniteHorizonLinearQuadraticRegulatorOptions`.

Comment: I've PR'd the option to configure the integrator: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19765

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out soon! I've implemented Riccati recursion (https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/notes/riccati-derivation.pdf) in the meantime to get it to work :)

Comment: To be clear, the Riccati recurions you linked is just the discrete time version of FiniteHorizonLQR. So it should be equivalent to setting the integrator to have a fixed timestep; it does not get around the stiffness problem (it should be thought of as an approximation which could be far from optimal).